# C++ tr1 on GCC 3.4.4 (for the Nokia N810 tablet computer)

Tags: c++, gcc, tr1

What does it take to get C++ **tr1** members (shared_ptr especially, but we'd like function and bind and ALL the others) working with **GCC 3.4.4** (for the Nokia **N810** tablet computer).

Has anyone done this?  Attempted this?

It may **not** be feasible for us to upgrade to GCC 4.x to cross-compile for this device (but if you've done that, we'd love to know).

There may be many approaches, and I'd like to avoid dead ends others have hit.

We're trying to avoid bringing in boost, since it can be pretty interdependent (you bring in one boost header and you end up with 20 more), and keeping code size down is important to us.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shared_ptr from boost, at least, the number of dependencies is pretty small. You can use [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html) to extract subsets from boost as well, so you don't need the whole of boost to compile your application.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) ([Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/), [Bind](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/), [Function](http://www.boost.org/libs/function/)) directly? From the [GCC changelogs](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html), the actual `std::tr1` stuff is only available from 4.0 onwards. :-(

I know there are differences between the Boost and `std::tr1`, but hopefully these can be worked around satisfactorily. Let me know how it works for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

On a different topic, I'm installing the `g++-3.4` package on my Ubuntu laptop now, and I'm going to see if I can compile `libstdc++` from the Subversion trunk on it. If so, I'll let you know! (If not, I'll let you know too. :-P)

Comment: Well, you didn't let anyone know eventually, did you? ;-)