# Hashtable in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, hashtable, complexity-theory

I usually use C++ stdlib map whenever I need to store some data associated with a specific type of value (a key value - e.g. a string or other object). The stdlib map implementation is based on trees which provides better performance (O(log n)) than the standard array or stdlib vector.

My questions is, do you know of any C++ "standard" hashtable implementation that provides even better performance (O(1))? Something similar to what is available in the Hashtable class from the Java API.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you're using C++11, you have access to the `<unordered_map>` and `<unordered_set>` headers. These provide classes [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

If you're using C++03 with TR1, you have access to the classes `std::tr1::unordered_map` and `std::tr1::unordered_set`, using the same headers (unless you're using GCC, in which case the headers are `<tr1/unordered_map>` and `<tr1/unordered_set>` instead).

In all cases, there are corresponding `unordered_multimap` and `unordered_multiset` types too.

Comment: In GCC, you have to use header names <tr1/unordered_map> and <tr1/unordered_set> instead. It's a GCC quirk. :-)

Comment: The VS2008 Feature Pack has been superseded by SP1.

Comment: IIRC the VC9 Feature Pack and SP1 tr1::unordered_* implementations came wih release notes warninig of sub-optimal performance.  I would assume that this will be fixed eventually.

Comment: Thanks, Ferruccio! I've incorporated your fix. (I apologise for misspelling your name in the edit comment, but I don't believe I now have a way to fix that.)

Answer (score 16):

If you don't already have unordered_map or unordered_set, they are part of [boost](http://www.boost.org/).
[Here's the documentation for both](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: Yay for Boost providing _maximal portability_ once again. :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131445 for another instance of this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) object as many here have mentioned, but it is not part of the stl.  It is a SGI extension, so if you were looking for something in the STL, I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has the class `stdext::hash_map` in the header `<hash_map>`, and gcc has the class `__gnu_cxx::hash_map` in the same header.

Comment: If they have the same interface, it's pretty easy to make an implementation that supports both of them using namespace aliases and some pre-processor work.

Comment: I know, I know, this is deprecated stuff. Not every collegue may be convinced to switch to VS 2008 or install Boost. So here is a good trick on how to get these together:

`  namespace std
  {
  #ifdef __GNUC__
   using namespace __gnu_cxx;
  #elif
   using namespace stdext;
  #endif
  }`

Answer (score 2):

std::tr1::unordered_map, in `<unordered_map>`

if you don't have tr1, get boost, and use
boost::unordered_map in `<boost/unordered_map.hpp>`

Answer (score 1):

See [std::hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) from SGI.

This is included in the [STLPort](http://www.stlport.com/doc/index.html) distribution as well.

Comment: It may be included in STLPort, but it's still not "standard", as the question sought after. There is no _standard_ class called hash_map; it's called unordered_map instead, and it's in TR1.

Answer (score 1):

hash_map is also supported in GNU's [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a00210.html).

Dinkumware also [supports](http://dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=hash_map.html#hash_map) this, which means that lots of implementations will have a hash_map (I think even Visual C++ delivers with Dinkumware).

Comment: It may be widely supported, but it's not "standard", as the questioner asked for. Only the TR1 facilities can be considered standard.

Comment: The point I was making is that if all the compiler vendors support it (or stdlibc++ vendors, as the case may be), then it may be a good enough substitute for "standard".  BTW, TR1 isn't "standard" yet.  It's accepted for the next standard, which is enough to get vendors to implement it (my point...)

Comment: I think that's just for libstdc++ version >= 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the TR1 extensions available for yor compiler, use those. If not, boost.org has a version that's quite similar except for the std:: namespace. In that case, put in a using-declaration so you can switch to std:: later.

Answer (score -1):

[std::hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)