# What is a C++ data structure that offers O(1) lookup?

Tags: c++, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashtable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c)

I was originally planning on using a C++ set for a hash-like data structure that offers O(1) lookup.

However, I realized that the complexity for lookup in sets is actually O(logn):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/find/

Is there a data structure akin to a hash table in C++ that offers O(1) lookup?

Comment: Array?  Or is that too simple to count?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Hash_tables

Comment: But for arrays, I must know how large of a data set I'm dealing with first, right?

Comment: I think the answer "Array" is meant to be a joke, based on the title of the question.

Comment: Oh :) Wait, could I use a vector perhaps to implement a hash fxn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 there's [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Look to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/unordered.html) if your compiler doesn't offer unordered_set.

Comment: Yeah, and [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) also.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use `vector`? That is better than array itself.