# how to find distinct substrings?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

Given a string, and a fixed length l, how can I count the number of distinct substrings whose length is l?
The size of character set is also known. (denote it as s)
For example, given a string "PccjcjcZ", s = 4, l = 3,
then there are 5 distinct substrings:
“Pcc”; “ccj”; “cjc”; “jcj”; “jcZ”

I try to use hash table, but the speed is still slow.
In fact I don't know how to use the character size.
I have done things like this

```
int diffPatterns(const string& src, int len, int setSize) {
  int cnt = 0;
  node* table[1 << 15];
  int tableSize = 1 << 15;
  for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
    table[i] = NULL;
  }

  unsigned int hashValue = 0;

  int end = (int)src.size() - len;

  for (int i = 0; i <= end; ++i) {
    hashValue = hashF(src, i, len);
    if (table[hashValue] == NULL) {
      table[hashValue] = new node(i);
      cnt ++;
    } else {
      if (!compList(src, i, table[hashValue], len)) {
        cnt ++;
      };
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; ++i) {
    deleteList(table[i]);
  }

  return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need to find all of the sub-strings or just the number of them?

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? You only want to make it faster?

Comment: @NathanOliver just the number

Comment: @tobi303 just faster

Comment: Just an idea: If there are no repeating substrings, you can simply calculate the number of distinct substrings from the lenght of the string. Maybe its easier to count and find the repeating substrings?

Comment: Build a DFA trie-style as you scan, every time you add a new node in the third tier, it's a new distinct substring.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this code spends most of its time filling `2^15` element array with `NULL`s. Just use `unordered_set<string>` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Hastables are fine and practical, but keep in mind that if the length of substrings is L, and the whole string length is N, then the algorithm is Theta((N+1-L)*L) which is Theta(NL) for most L. Remember, just computing the hash takes Theta(L) time. Plus there might be collisions.

Suffix trees can be used, and provide a guaranteed O(N) time algorithm (count number of paths at depth L or greater), but the implementation is complicated. Saving grace is you can probably find off the shelf implementations in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a hashtable is good. It should work well.

The idea of implementing your own hashtable as an array of length 2^15 is bad. See [Hashtable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133569/hashtable-in-c?lq=1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`unorder_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) and insert the strings into the set and then get the size of the set.  Since the values in a set are unique it will take care of not including substrings that are the same as ones previously found.  This should give you close to O(StringSize - SubstringSize) complexity

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>


int main()
{
    std::string test = "PccjcjcZ";
    std::unordered_set<std::string> counter;
    size_t substringSize = 3;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test.size() - substringSize + 1; ++i)
    {
        counter.insert(test.substr(i, substringSize));
    }

    std::cout << counter.size();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veronica Kham answered good to the question, but we can improve this method  to expected `O(n)` and still use a simple hash table rather than suffix tree or any other advanced data structure.

### Hash function

Let `X` and `Y` are two adjacent substrings of length `L`, more precisely:

`X = A[i, i + L - 1]`

`Y = B[i + 1, i + 1 + L - 1]`

Let assign to each letter of our alphabet a single non negative integer, for example `a := 1, b := 2` and so on.

Let's define a hash function `h` now:

`h(A[i, j]) := (P^(L-1) * A[i] + P^(L-2) * A[i + 1] + ... + A[j]) % M`

where `P` is a prime number ideally greater than the alphabet size and `M` is a very big number denoting the number of different possible hashes, for example you can set `M` to maximum available `unsigned long long int` in your system.

### Algorithm

The crucial observation is the following:

> If you have a hash computed for `X`, you can compute a hash for `Y` in
> `O(1)` time.

Let assume that we have computed `h(X)`, which can be done in `O(L)` time obviously. We want to compute `h(Y)`. Notice that since `X` and `Y` differ by only 2 characters, and we can do that easily using addition and multiplication:

`h(Y) = ((h(X) - P^L * A[i]) * P) + A[j + 1]) % M`

Basically, we are subtracting letter A[i] multiplied by its coefficient in `h(X)`, multiplying the result by `P` in order to get proper coefficients for the rest of letters and at the end, we are adding the last letter `A[j + 1]`.

Notice that we can precompute powers of `P` at the beginning and we can do it modulo `M`.

Since our hashing functions returns integers, we can use any hash table to store them. Remember to make all computations modulo `M` and avoid integer overflow.

### Collisions

Of course, there might occur a collision, but since `P` is prime and `M` is really huge, it is a rare situation.

If you want to lower the probability of a collision, you can use two different hashing functions, for example by using different modulo in each of them. If probability of a collision is `p` using one such function, then for two functions it is `p^2` and we can make it arbitrary small by this trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rolling hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash).

This will make the runtime expected O(n).

This might be repeating pkacprzak's answer, except, it gives a name for easier remembrance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Suffix Automaton also can finish it in O(N).

It's easy to code, but hard to understand.

Here are papers about it http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=375360.375365

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397509002370